# How many processes & RAM I should assign to my SharePoint VM development environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, vmware

I have a machine with the following specifications:-

1. 32 GB RAM
2. Core i7 with 8 processes.
3. 670 GB hard disk.
4. Windows 7 professional.
5. Inside the machine I installed VM workstation 9.0 .

And I have defined the following specification for the VM:-

1. 24 GB of RAM
2. 4 processes.
3. 80 GB of hard disk
4. I install SharePoint 2013 server , SQL server 2008 r2 sp2 , visual studio 2013, and TFS.

Currently the VM is working well, but I have the following question about my setup:-

1. Will it cause any problem if I assign all the available 8 processes to the VM instead of 4.
2. Will it cause any problem if I assign the available 32 RAM to the VM instead of 24 GB.
3. I have changed the number of processes assigned to the VM from 1(default) to 4 , but I am unable to changed it again to 1 processes (if I need in the future)?

Thanks

Comment: Even though it's development machine but make sure you hard disk is of dynamic size not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like OK specs. The more service applications you are planning to use, the more power you will need.

I do not think it sounds wise to let the Virtual maschine use all of the RAM, your host needs RAM aswell.

Also regarding the CPU, give the VM maximum 6 cores, or configure the VM to not utilize 100% of each core. This also to give the host machine some working space.

Comment: but if the VM is shutdown then none of the RAM or processes will be used by the VM..

Comment: Well you can't really have it started without also having your host started, right? So therefore you need to spare some resources for the host. But when it is turned off, your host will still be able to use all of its capacity.

Comment: thanks so i mean i can assign the VM most of the resources and keep 1 GB RAM and 2 processes for the host, instead 8 GB and 4 processes?

Comment: Probably, you can check how much your host is using when you have not started the VM to get an idea of how much to spare